# Determine if an observable stream is in progress and present a loader based on it

Tags: angular, rxjs

**My use case:**

1. I have service store that handle a `customer` model. The `customer` model is exposed as an observable.
2. On that service, I have several methods that trigger the customer change like `load`, `update`. Those trigger a subject that sub streams listen on. There is also a sub stream for the `customer` that listen on socket update for that customer and update it with new data.

I want to block a component and show a spinner while the action on customer stream is doing something, meaning loading, updating..

**Customer Store Service**

If the customer service looks like this:

```js
class CustomerService {
  customerStreamInProgress$ = /* how to calculate it */

  customer$ = this.streamCustomer();
  // ...
  streamCustomer() {
    return rx.pipe(
      () => merge(
        this.streamCustomerFromLoad(),
        this.streamCustomerFromUpdate(),
        this.streamCustomerFromSocket(),
      ),
      shareReplay(/* refcount 1*/),
    )(null):
  }

  streamCustomerFromLoad() {
    return rx.pipe(
      () => this.loadCustomerAction$,
      switchMap(cusotmerId => this.customerRestApi.fetchCustomer(customerId)),
    )(null);
  }

  // ... other methods the same design pattern.

  loadCustomer(id: number) {
    this.loadCustomerAction$.next(id);
  }
}
```

**Component Template**

In the template, I want to show spinner/blocker each time the customer stream is in progress.

```html
<div class="customer spinner-directive="customerStore.customerStreamInProgress$ | async">
  <span>Name: {{ (customerStore.customer$ | async).name }}<span>
  ....
</div>
```

**What I have tried**

1. I have done it manually, meaning adding new behavior subject to the store and putting `tap`, `catchError`, `finalize` in every place i can think of and setting that to false and true when actions start and end.
2. I have started thinking about augmenting the rxjs operators/observables to expose on the observable they provide a custom `_inProgress$` property and have them concatenate what observable they get before so I can combine operators and before that get `inProgress$` property on each final observable I construct.

Option 2 is very hacky.
Option 1 is very verbose.

Does anyone have experience with better design pattern to do this so the code for the streams won't be so verbose and I would not have to hack the original operators/observables.

Answer (score 2):

I maybe don't have a exact solution for you, but 2 recommendations you possibly want to use for your case.

**1st In case of HTTP requests use interceptor**

Something like

```
export class HttpRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private _loading: LoadingService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this._loading.setLoading(true, request.url);
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(catchError((err) => {
        this._loading.setLoading(false, request.url);
        return err;
      }))
      .pipe(map<HttpEvent<any>, any>((evt: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this._loading.setLoading(false, request.url);
        }
        return evt;
      }));
  }
}
```

Read further: https://medium.com/swlh/angular-loading-spinner-using-http-interceptor-63c1bb76517b

**2nd Use a structural directive**

Nils Melhorn created the ngx-observe directive. It provides a directive, which requires an observable and lets you define a template for `loading`, `error` and `next`, where the `loading` template can easily be used to show the spinner.

GitHub: https://github.com/nilsmehlhorn/ngx-observe
NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-observe
A blog post: https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/angular-observable-directive

Comment: First of all, thank you for the time. Its Much appreciated. Regarding the solutions: 1. I'v looked into the interceptor and it aspect oriented to general or per url. I am trying to block  for specific streams. Some streams can use the same api url calls.
2. Looking at `ngx-observe` code, it seems it show the loading template only on subscribe. Its not dealing with long running streams and detecting active processing in them.